# Can I Merge or Join these tables?

Tags: sql

I have a few tables that are having different columns and values but would like to merge/join these together

The tables look like this:

```
A
Datetime        ID  A   B   C   D
1/1/2018 00:00:00   1   11  22  33  44
2/1/2018 00:00:00   1   11  22  33  44
3/1/2018 00:00:00   1   11  22  33  44
4/1/2018 00:00:00   1   11  22  33  44
5/1/2018 00:00:00   1   11  22  33  44
6/1/2018 00:00:00   1   11  22  33  44


B
Datetime        ID  E   F   G   H
1/2/2018 00:00:00   2   101 212 313 414
2/2/2018 00:00:00   2   101 212 313 441
3/2/2018 00:00:00   2   101 212 313 414
4/2/2018 00:00:00   2   101 212 313 414
5/2/2018 00:00:00   2   101 212 313 441
6/2/2018 00:00:00   2   101 212 313 441


C
Datetime        ID  I   J   K   L
1/3/2018 00:00:00   3   11  22  33  44
2/3/2018 00:00:00   3   11  22  33  44
3/3/2018 00:00:00   3   11  22  33  44
4/3/2018 00:00:00   3   11  22  33  44
5/3/2018 00:00:00   3   11  22  33  44
6/3/2018 00:00:00   3   11  22  33  44
```

i WANt my final table to look like this:

FINAL A

```
Datetime        ID  A   B   C   D
1/1/2018 00:00:00   1   11  22  33  44
2/1/2018 00:00:00   1   11  22  33  44
3/1/2018 00:00:00   1   11  22  33  44
4/1/2018 00:00:00   1   11  22  33  44
5/1/2018 00:00:00   1   11  22  33  44
6/1/2018 00:00:00   1   11  22  33  44


B
Datetime        ID  E   F   G   H
1/2/2018 00:00:00   2   101 212 313 414
2/2/2018 00:00:00   2   101 212 313 441
3/2/2018 00:00:00   2   101 212 313 414
4/2/2018 00:00:00   2   101 212 313 414
5/2/2018 00:00:00   2   101 212 313 441
6/2/2018 00:00:00   2   101 212 313 441


C
Datetime        ID  I   J   K   L
1/3/2018 00:00:00   3   11  22  33  44
2/3/2018 00:00:00   3   11  22  33  44
3/3/2018 00:00:00   3   11  22  33  44
4/3/2018 00:00:00   3   11  22  33  44
5/3/2018 00:00:00   3   11  22  33  44
6/3/2018 00:00:00   3   11  22  33  44
```

FINAL

```
Datetime        ID  A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J   K   L
1/1/2018 00:00:00   1   11  22  33  44
2/1/2018 00:00:00   1   11  22  33  44
3/1/2018 00:00:00   1   11  22  33  44
4/1/2018 00:00:00   1   11  22  33  44
5/1/2018 00:00:00   1   11  22  33  44
6/1/2018 00:00:00   1   11  22  33  44
1/2/2018 00:00:00   2                   101 212 313 414
2/2/2018 00:00:00   2                   101 212 313 441
3/2/2018 00:00:00   2                   101 212 313 414
4/2/2018 00:00:00   2                   101 212 313 414
5/2/2018 00:00:00   2                   101 212 313 441
6/2/2018 00:00:00   2                   101 212 313 441
1/3/2018 00:00:00   3                                   11  22  33  44
2/3/2018 00:00:00   3                                   11  22  33  44
3/3/2018 00:00:00   3                                   11  22  33  44
4/3/2018 00:00:00   3                                   11  22  33  44
5/3/2018 00:00:00   3                                   11  22  33  44
6/3/2018 00:00:00   3                                   11  22  33  44
```

I cant think of the logic as each tables have its own column but i want it to be merged as per above.

Seeking for your advise.

Comment: What version of SQL are you using (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, Postgres, etc.) ?

Answer (score 1):

We can do this via a union query:

```
SELECT Datetime, ID, A, B, C, D, NULL AS E, NULL AS F, NULL AS G, NULL AS H,
    NULL AS I, NULL AS J, NULL AS K, NULL AS L
FROM A
UNION ALL
SELECT Datetime, ID, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, E, F, G, H, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
FROM B
UNION ALL
SELECT Datetime, ID, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, I, J, K, L
FROM C
ORDER BY
    ID, Datetime;
```

[image]

### Demo

Note: It is *not* necessary to repeat column aliases which appear in the first select of a union query in subsequent selects.  In fact, such aliases will just be ignored.

Demo given in SQL Server arbitrarily because of easy setup, but the query should run on pretty much any database.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Datetime,ID,A,B,C,D,NULL AS E,NULL AS F,NULL AS G,NULL AS H,NULL AS I,NULL AS J,NULL AS K,NULL AS L
FROM TableA
UNION ALL
SELECT Datetime,ID,NULL AS A,NULL AS B,NULL AS C,NULL AS D, E,F,G,H,NULL AS I,NULL AS J,NULL AS K,NULL AS L
FROM TableB
UNION ALL
SELECT Datetime,ID,NULL AS A,NULL AS B,NULL AS C,NULL AS D,NULL AS AS E,NULL AS AS F,NULL AS G,NULL AS H,I,J,K,L
FROM TableC
```

Answer (score 0):

Use UNION ALL:

```
select Datetime,ID,  A,   B,   C,   D,   null as E,  null as F,   null as G,   null as H,   null as I,   null as J,   null as K,   null as L from tableA
union all
select Datetime,ID, null,   null ,  null ,  null ,    E,   F,   G,   H,   null ,   null ,   null ,   null  from tableB
Union all
select Datetime,ID,  null ,   null ,   null ,   null ,   null ,  null ,   null ,   H,   I,   J,   K,   L from tableC
```